# Excel Formula Bar - When Text is Highlighted, Prevent Clicking Cells From Editing Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Pretty much the title.  I've never edited formulas by clicking around.  Anyway to prevent that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Formula entry (in a cell) will always insert a reference to a cell, as you click on another cell than the one you're editing.

The first "text" (e.g. of a formula) that you enter in a cell sets a special mode that allows cursor movements to insert a cell reference; is that what you wish to avoid?

If yes:
As soon as there is any content in the cell before you edit it, you can avoid the cursor issue by using `F2` to enter edit mode for the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks Hannu but I'm actually talking about the formula bar.  It's an optional future but it exists by default.  It's where the formula will always be spelled out between the ribbon and the spreadsheet itself.  Essentially I'm copying formulas into technical documentation.  The formula bar makes it easier to grab the entire function rather than double clicking on a cell.  Once I've copied the formula I can avoid my issue by immediately hitting escape.  And if I start overwriting the formula I can back out by hitting escape.  I'm just trying to avoid the extra escape pressing

Comment: This is also more than I one time issue.  I randomly do things like this in Excel every so often.  I guess my ultimate goal is to really prevent clicking around from ever being able to build a formula.

Comment: I know of no way to avoid the hazzle, unless there is a new setting somewhere in excel.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the attempt to help anyway.